# PHP SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition connection timeout

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, database-connection

I've searched through endless solutions for connection problems with PHP and SQL Server 2005 and still no luck. I'm using SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition.
Here's the code:

```
$server = "MYLAP01\\SQLEXPRESS";
$options = array("Database" => "test1");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);

if ($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));echo "Successfully connected!";

sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

And the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => HYT00
            [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => -1
            [code] => -1
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        )

)
```

Comment: Fixed this by adding the port number: $server = "MYLAP01\\SQLEXPRESS,1433";

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding the port number: $server = "MYLAP01\SQLEXPRESS,1433";